# What is the correct way (or better place) to use topLayoutGuide/bottomLayourGuide in code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, constraints, viewcontroller

Assume you do not want to use storyboards and instead programmatically create your viewControllers / views and autolayout them by code also. How do you properly make use of topLayoutGuide and bottomLayoutGuide? They are properties of the viewController. 
I might be wrong, but I think the proper place to set constraints for autolayout are the relevant views and they usually are not supposed to have references to their viewControllers (again afaik).

Am I mistaken and the coding of constraints should be done in the viewController or if not, how do you get the information down to the views?

Please be patient I am learning ;-)

Comment: It's fine to add your constraints in the view controller. Apple recommends querying topLayoutGuide and bottomLayoutGuide in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method, which is a UIViewController method.

Comment: Thank you for commenting on this question of mine too :-) 
I might just've found the apple-doc you're referring to. 
For querrying topLayoutGuide they suggest to call viewDidLayoutSubviews in viewControllers and/or layoutSubviews in views. But I'm still torn between both ways – coding constraints in a viewcontroller requires you to save references to all relevant subviews making at least reusing of any code parts rather difficult. While the other way around (getting a reference to a viewController from a view) is often labeled bad coding.
I'm surprised that there seems no really „neat“ way.